# OpenVPN fails with invalid secrets

Tags: openvpn

I followed these set of instructions:
https://www.ipredator.se/guide/openvpn/ubuntu/gnome

But unfortunately, when I connect it fails saying that invalid secrets are the cause. I'm quite sure that my credentials are correct, and network-manager has definitely been restarted.

The syslog output  have is here:

```
Dec 22 11:36:13 desktop-1 NetworkManager[972]:  VPN service 'openvpn' started (org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.openvpn), PID 3215
Dec 22 11:36:13 desktop-1 NetworkManager[972]:  VPN service 'openvpn' appeared; activating connections
Dec 22 11:36:13 desktop-1 NetworkManager[972]:  VPN plugin state changed: 1
Dec 22 11:36:13 desktop-1 NetworkManager[972]:  VPN plugin state changed: 3
Dec 22 11:36:13 desktop-1 NetworkManager[972]:  VPN connection 'Ipredator-openvpn' (Connect) reply received.
Dec 22 11:36:13 desktop-1 nm-openvpn[3219]: OpenVPN 2.2.0 i686-linux-gnu [SSL] [LZO2] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [eurephia] [MH] [PF_INET6] [IPv6 payload 20110424-2 (2.2RC2)] built on Jul  4 2011
Dec 22 11:36:14 desktop-1 NetworkManager[972]:  (wlan0): IP6 addrconf timed out or failed.
Dec 22 11:36:14 desktop-1 NetworkManager[972]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IP6 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
Dec 22 11:36:14 desktop-1 NetworkManager[972]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IP6 Configure Timeout) started...
Dec 22 11:36:14 desktop-1 NetworkManager[972]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 5 of 5 (IP Configure Commit) started...
Dec 22 11:36:14 desktop-1 NetworkManager[972]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 5 of 5 (IP Configure Commit) complete.
Dec 22 11:36:14 desktop-1 NetworkManager[972]:  Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IP6 Configure Timeout) complete.
Dec 22 11:36:14 desktop-1 nm-openvpn[3219]: WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
Dec 22 11:36:14 desktop-1 nm-openvpn[3219]: NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
Dec 22 11:36:14 desktop-1 nm-openvpn[3219]: WARNING: file '/home/desktop/vpn/IPredator.se.ta.key' is group or others accessible
Dec 22 11:36:14 desktop-1 nm-openvpn[3219]: Control Channel Authentication: using '/home/desktop/vpn/IPredator.se.ta.key' as a OpenVPN static key file
Dec 22 11:36:14 desktop-1 nm-openvpn[3219]: LZO compression initialized
Dec 22 11:36:14 desktop-1 nm-openvpn[3219]: RESOLVE: NOTE: pw.openvpn.ipredator.se resolves to 10 addresses
Dec 22 11:36:14 desktop-1 nm-openvpn[3219]: UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Dec 22 11:36:14 desktop-1 nm-openvpn[3219]: UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]xxx.xxx.xxx
Dec 22 11:36:16 desktop-1 nm-openvpn[3219]: [pw.openvpn.ipredator.se] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]xxx.xxx.xxx
Dec 22 11:36:19 desktop-1 nm-openvpn[3219]: AUTH: Received AUTH_FAILED control message
Dec 22 11:36:19 desktop-1 nm-openvpn[3219]: SIGTERM[soft,auth-failure] received, process exiting
Dec 22 11:36:19 desktop-1 NetworkManager[972]:  VPN plugin failed: 0
Dec 22 11:36:19 desktop-1 NetworkManager[972]:  VPN plugin state changed: 6
Dec 22 11:36:19 desktop-1 NetworkManager[972]:  VPN plugin state change reason: 10
Dec 22 11:36:19 desktop-1 NetworkManager[972]:  error disconnecting VPN: Could not process the request because no VPN connection was active.
Dec 22 11:36:19 desktop-1 NetworkManager[972]:  Policy set 'wireless' (wlan0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
Dec 22 11:36:25 desktop-1 NetworkManager[972]:  VPN service 'openvpn' disappeared
```

Answer (score 1):

you probably used special characters within your password and use the openVPN connection. OpenVPN cannot handle special characters well.

Try to use only alphanumeric chars in your (long and secure) password and see if it works then.